# Google sheets increases the height of a cell after return key is pressed to exit a cell

Tags: google-sheets

As the following image demonstrates, pressing the return key on a cell, after entering content, randomly increases the cell height.

Sometimes this does occur (1 in 10ish) and sometimes it doesn't.  Any ideas as to why?

(here is a video just to show you how it occurs https://youtu.be/0B1NtJb8djU)

[image]

Comment: What font size do you use?

Comment: I use the default, nothing changed (I just zoomed in for the picture)